# how to maintain user session after app is updated

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble in releasing an existing app in playstore. After the user has logged in from previous version in production, with the app still running in background i performed the update on the same app which I released. The update was successful although it prompts user to log in again.Is it possible to retain the user session after the newly updated app is opened??.

P.S: In short , I have to access the cache memory of previous version code in publication and use it in current android version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this just store user's credentials along with a flag like LOGGED_IN = true; in shared preferences, this way maintain a a session until user does not log out. And if user logs out then just update flag to  LOGGED_IN = false; and check with this condition if user is logged in or not.

Comment: I tried that , with every new update in the playstore the previous caches of the previous released version is getting cleared. so i am getting undesired value from them if i refer them in the new app.

Comment: This should be happening. May be something in your data might be affecting the app. Can you post your code?